# Normal curvature of geodesic spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, geodesic, lipschitz-functions, spheres

I would like to ask the community for a reference on the following property of geodesic spheres. Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold without conjugate points and $\tilde{M}$ its universal covering with the natural metric $\tilde{g}$. Given a point $\tilde{p}\in\tilde{M}$ and $R>1$, Is there some result like

*The inner normal field of the geodesic sphere centered at $\tilde{p}$ and with radius $R$ is a Lipschitz vector field*?

I am aware that the normal curvature satisfies a Riccati equation along a geodesi radius starting at the center of the sphere, namely $\tilde{p}$. Perhaps I could get some control of the normal vector field of a geodesic sphere using this equation, but I don't know if there is this control.

If someone could give me any reference on the subject, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: In your setting the field is smooth, in particular Lipschitz.

Comment: Hi, @AntonPetrunin, indeed. Allow me to go a little further on my question. I see that if I fix the radius $R$, the normal vector is Lipschitz as you pointed out, and it appears to me that the Lipschitz constant $L$ will depend on $R$. Letting the radius $R>1$ be arbitrary large (in the abscense of conjugate points), do you have any feeling on if it is possible to have some upper bound for the Lipschitz constants?

Comment: Dear @NormalHuman, this is a nice example, thank you. I can't see if it is possible for this example to be the universal covering of a compact Riemannian manifold. If it is not, perhaps I can have some hope. I'm interested in investigate this Lipschitz constant in universal coverings of compact Riemannian manifolds without conjugate points.

Comment: Lipschitz smooth vector field. Euler normal curvature for the tangent bundle is always constant. $ k1=k2=k=1/R ;\; k_n=k1 \cos^2 \alpha+k2 \sin^2\alpha= k=1/R$